# How to compare two datetimes

Tags: .net, datetime, compare, equals, compareto

I wonder how to compare two DateTime objects in .NET using DateTime methods `Compare`, `CompareTo` or `Equals` without comparing ticks.

I only need a tolerance level of milliseconds or seconds.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subtract one `DateTime` from another to produce a `TimeSpan` that represents the time-difference between them. You can then test if the *absolute value* of this span is within your desired tolerance.

```
bool dtsWithinASecOfEachOther = d1.Subtract(d2).Duration() <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

The call to `TimeSpan.Duration()` can be omitted if you know that the first `DateTime` cannot represent an earlier point in time than the other, i.e. `d1 >= d2`.

To answer your query about the comparison methods, 
[`DateTime.Compare(d1, d2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) produces the same result as [`d1.CompareTo(d2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx):

- 0 if they represent the same point in time (`d1.Equals(d2)` , `d1 == d2`). Do note though, that the resolution of DateTime is 1 tick = 100 nanoseconds = 10 ^ -7 seconds.
- A value greater than 0 if d1 is chronologically after d2 (`d1 > d2`)
- A value less than 0  if d1 is chronologically before d2 (`d1 < d2`)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.timespan.aspx) for your tolerance check - `TimeSpan` is the type returned from subtracting DateTimes:

```
TimeSpan tolerance = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
return (date1 - date2) <= tolerance;
```

`Compare`, `CompareTo` and `Equals` will not take a tolerance for the comparison, so cannot used this way.

Other options are to create new `DateTime`s from the existing ones, discarding the unwanted accuracy and comparing the new ones:

```
DateTime noSeconds1 = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, d1.Hour, d1.Minute, 0);
DateTime noSeconds2 = new DateTime(d2.Year, d2.Month, d2.Day, d2.Hour, d2.Minute, 0);

noSeconds1.Equals(noSeconds2);
DateTime.Compare(noSeconds1, noSeconds2);
noSeconds1.CompareTo(noSeconds2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you want a single compare to tell you which date is less, equal to or greater, use DateTime.Compare(). Otherwise, you can use DateTime.Equals(). To add a tolerance value, subtract one from the other and compare result to be less than some TimeSpan:

```
// For seconds
if (laterDate-earlierDate<=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
  ...

// For milliseconds
if (laterDate-earlierDate<=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert both DateTimes to string and compare the resulting strings. Make sure you define the string format to avoid problems on machines with different regional settings than yours.